# Validation of date in mm.dd.yyyy format using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Since I couldn't get any solution for my question related to jQuery datapicker, I thought I might need to write a code to verify the date myself. I have a textbox with date in format mm.dd.yyyy. How can I validate date in textbox should not be greater than the current date on blur?

```
Reminder.config = {
    BaseURL: "Reminder.ashx?" + Reminder.BaseURLQuery,
    tblHistory: "#tblHistory",
    txtNotes: "#txtNotes",
    txtDate: "#txtDate",
    btnSave: "#btnSave",
    dateFormat: 'mm.dd.yy',
};

Reminder.Init = function () {
//Set up calendar 
var $txtDate = $(Reminder.config.txtDate);
$txtDate.datepicker({
    dateFormat: Reminder.config.dateFormat,
    onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
        try {
            $.datepicker.parseDate(Reminder.config.dateFormat, dateText);
        } catch (e) {
            $txtDate.val('');
        };
    },
    maxDate: '+0'
});

$txtDate.datepicker('setDate', new Date()).blur(function () {
        try {
            if ($txtDate.val() == '') {
                $txtDate.datepicker('setDate', new Date());
            }            
        }
        catch (ex) {
            var myEx = myWeb.Exception(ex);
            myEx.AddData("Method", "$txtDate.datepicker('setDate', new Date()).blur");
        }
    });

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're already constraining your date picker to not select dates in the future.
But you don't say what seems to be the problem with that... Anyway...

A blur even handler like this one should work as expected:

```
$txtDate.blur(function(e){
    // this is now
    var now = new Date();

    // let date picker parse the date since it has formatting set
    var date = $txtDate.datepicker("getDate");

    // is date ok then?
    if ((date || new Date()) >= now)
    {
        alert("Does not compute");
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually the datepicker control greys out the future date but it doesn't restrict the user to edit the future date in the corresponding textbox. I thought, maxDate should handle it but it didn't. So I thought of adding a code to blur event to check programatically.

Comment: @kuul13: Yes I've tested it myself as well. You either have two options: prevent user input on that textbox or use the blur event handler I've provided.

Answer (score 0):

I would begin by parse()ing the supplied date from the textbox, and comparing it's getTime() return value with that of the (new Date()).getTime() return value.

If the first is greater than the latter, your supplied date lies in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) to validate any date format